# Bind Selected Item in DXGrid using MVVM

Tags: mvvm, devexpress, selecteditem

I have a ViewModel in a WPF Application with these two properties:

```
public Customer Customer { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
```

Inside my view I Have a DXGrid. How do I bind the selected item to the customer property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`SelectedRowsSource`](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E3139.aspx) property. Bind it to `ObservableCollection<Customer>`. Your code will look like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<Customer> SelectedCustomers { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
```

....

```
    <dxg:GridControl ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" AutoPopulateColumns="True">
        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView MultiSelectMode="Row" NavigationStyle="Row" 
                 SelectedRowsSource="{Binding SelectedCustomers}" />
        </dxg:GridControl.View>
    </dxg:GridControl>
```

Comment: Now it Works but i'll add a little note the SelectedCustomer must be initialized! - Thank you for the answare!

Comment: @MatteoViatorMurdocco of course it must be initialized. It's obvious :)

Comment: if in a normal DataGrid i bind to the SelectedItem to a single element element = null unselect the element!